# error with running matplotlib/pymc in screen

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, gnu-screen, pymc

When I run Matplot.plot in pymc, I use screen to suspend it. After it done, some
error show up:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:10.0"
```

I have tried ioff(), but it didn't work.
Is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: This is due to a poor mixing of screen with xwindows.  I am sure this can be done, as the gui bits and pieces of `matplotlib` are tied to the xserver they are started on, when you resume the screen session, you may (will?) have a different display/xserver.  My (hazy) understanding was that `screen` and gui's don't play nice, full stop.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9920/x11-forwarding-over-gnu-screen-is-it-possible

Comment: http://ask.metafilter.com/79852/Is-there-an-X-Windows-GNU-screen-equivalent

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10597/gnu-screen-for-x11-forwarding